# Arrow in spectral sequence oriented wrongly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a spectral sequence make in Tikz, but the arrowhead is oriented strangely, and all the different options I have tried won't correct this. The code is included below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}\label{SSS1}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
  \matrix (m) \[matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum width=5ex,
    minimum height=5ex,outer sep=-5pt},
    column sep=1ex,row sep=1ex\]{
                &      &     &     &    & \\
          3     & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\\
          2     &  \Z^6 & 0 & 0 & \Z^6 &\\   
          1     &  0 &  0  & 0 & 0&\\
          0     &  \Z  & 0 &  0  & \Z&\\
    \quad\strut &   0  &  1  &  2  & 3 & p\strut \\};
    \draw\[-stealth\] (m-3-2.south east) -- (m-5-5.north west)-|  node \[above,pos=0.5\] {$d_3$}(m-5-5.north west);
\draw\[thick\] (m-1-1.east) -- (m-6-1.east) ;
\draw\[thick\] (m-6-1.north) -- (m-6-6.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have included an image below, so that you can see the the arrowhead is pointing up instead of down and to the right; it should just point in the direction of the line.[image: Spectral Sequence]

Comment: `\draw[-stealth] (m-3-2.south east) -- (m-5-5.north west) 
  node [above,pos=0.5] {$d_3$};` works, you just added the `-|` piece along with an extra node so Ti*k*Z is following these instructions. Also load the matrix library in the preamble of the document and AFAIK putting a label in a tikzpicture is not very efficient.

Comment: Not a TikZ expert, but what is the `-|` doing there? It might be related to the problem.

Comment: @marmot Thanks so much, that fixed the problem! Do you want to make it an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an excess piece in the path, `-|` and the extra node. The following works:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,nodes={minimum width=5ex,
    minimum height=5ex,outer sep=-5pt},
    column sep=1ex,row sep=1ex]{
                &      &     &     &    & \\
          3     & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\\
          2     &  \Z^6 & 0 & 0 & \Z^6 &\\   
          1     &  0 &  0  & 0 & 0&\\
          0     &  \Z  & 0 &  0  & \Z&\\
    \quad\strut &   0  &  1  &  2  & 3 & p\strut \\};
    \draw[-stealth] (m-3-2.south east) -- (m-5-5.north west) 
     node [above,pos=0.5] {$d_3$};
\draw[thick] (m-1-1.east) -- (m-6-1.east) ;
\draw[thick] (m-6-1.north) -- (m-6-6.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Apart from working this is a so-called MWE, i.e. a little compilable document that everyone can copy and (hopefully) compile. I moved the matrix library to the preamble and also removed `\label`, which may make more sense after `\caption` of a figure, say.

Comment: Again, thanks so much, and for the advice about the tikzlibrary!